# How to render page by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How can i render page by jQuery in Yii2, like this code?

```
<script>
    function showIndex(){
        <?php $this->renderAjax(['index']); ?>
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to replace any html portion inside Jquery ? Your view is already rendered , you can either redirect to another action or update a portion of your DOM

Comment: I want something like this: $('#product').load(<?php $this->renderAjax(['index']); ?>);

Answer (score 0):

You should try this way, because you have wrong syntax.

```
<script>
    function showIndex(){
        <?php $this->renderAjax('index', []); ?>
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I want to render the page when i click link.

Answer (score 0):

In your view file before script add the following

```
<?php
   $data = $this->renderFile('@app/views/......'); // provide exact filepath 
   $data = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $data));
?>
```

Your script function

```
<script>
   function showIndex(){
       $('#product').html(<?php echo $data; ?>);
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved,

```
<script>
    function productAction(id) {
        $('#product').load(id);
    }
</script>

    Html::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>', [
        'onclick' => 'productAction(\'' . Url::to(['/product/index']) . '\')',
        'title' => 'show',
        'class' => 'showModalButton btn btn-default',
        'style' => 'float:left']);
    ?>
```